# Unable to Start Monitor Mode on External Network Adapter Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng

I've recently installed some drivers for my TP-LINK TL-WN722N v2 external network adapter on my Kali Linux.

I'm trying to set the network card into monitor mode but I receive the following output when using airmon-ng:

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng check kill; airmon-ng start wlan1

Killing these processes:

  PID Name
 3549 wpa_supplicant



PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       b43     Broadcom on bcma bus, information limited
null    wlan1       r8188eu
```

Notice under `PHY` my wlan1 network is shown as `null`. I'm sure this has something to do with the issue. The command does nothing after running it.

Any ideas how I can enable monitor mode on my network adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Actually 0xSheepdog is right.

V2 has Realtek RTL8188 chipset which WILL NOT WORK WITH Kali. It doesn't support monitor mode and packet injection.

The only way to get above things to work, is to return V2 and buy V1 (You can check bottom of tp-link box, to check model if it's not V2)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Table showing Chip ID and PCI-ID to find supported mode.]

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43

I wanted to give you and everyone else a more definitive answer about the support of TP-Link TL-WN722N V2/2.1. It's been slightly over a year and the WN722N (among others) continue to be AWESOME and affordable tool in Kali - specifically with airmon-ng support.

I've been using the Version 2.1 for a few months now with success (better success with a upgraded antenna, next in list) and have found confusing information (rather outdated) and wanted to help close thread with a positive end.

The chipset my card (same mentioned above, WN722N v2.1) when running terminal [ I'm running with root permission (Kali 2018.2 Debian), if not in root - simply type 'su' followed by the password. example - user1:su ]

root: lspci -vnn

When scrolling to find my card, under Network controller, it states -

> Broadcom Limited   BCM4331   802.11a/b/g/n   [14e4:4331] (rev 02)'

Chip ID/Chipset BCM43xx (4331 in our case), quoting from ' https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=broadcom'

> "As of 2.6.17, a driver for the Broadcom bcm43xx wireless chipset has been included in the kernel. Older Kernels can sometimes be made to work, check out recources..."

Short answer - Yes, it now works and is supported, confirmed through site and personal usage.

#### EDIT - I noticed you also entered the wrong card to start airmon-ng ;)

Pay attention to the name on the right and enter the correct 'wlan'
. Hopefully you figured that out before this but note to any new readers still looking.

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! :-)

Comment: Thank you very very much for this answer!! I gave up on trying a while ago, but if i come back to this, I will definately give this answer a shot. I'm sure it will help many others too!

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search suggests your V2 does not have the chipset which supports rfmon mode.

[Quora.com post](https://www.quora.com/Can-TP-Link-TL-WN722N-be-used-for-packet-sniffing-and-packet-injection-in-Kali-Linux)

Other Google results suggest the Realtek r8188eu chipset is problematic in Linux. Looks like you have a substandard adapter for the task in Kali. :\

Comment: Uhm, why a -1 ?